# how to auto select in check box when the selection box is selected in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do to auto select in check box when the selection box is selected in the same row. 
Although I found this question in stackoverflow, unfortunately it didn't match my requirement. So, please give me some suggestions.

There are many rows in a table. In each row, there has one check box and one selection box in each column.If I selected something in selection box in a row, I want to do auto check in check box in the same row.

I wrote the code as the following.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sel_ActList_status').change(function() {
            $('.sel_ActList_status').parent('td').silbings('td').find(".chk_ActList_select").checked = true;
            //$('.sel_ActList_status').parent('td').silbings('td').find(".chk_ActList_select").prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="chk_ActList_select[0]" class="chk_ActList_select" type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk_ActList_select[0]">
        </td>
        <td>xxxxx</td>
        <td>
            <select id="sel_ActList_status" class="sel_ActList_status" name="sel_ActList_status">
                <option selected="selected" value="2">11111</option>
                <option value="0">22222</option>
                <option value="1">33333</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="chk_ActList_select[1]" class="chk_ActList_select" type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk_ActList_select[1]">
        </td>
        <td>xxxxx</td>
        <td>
            <select id="sel_ActList_status" class="sel_ActList_status" name="sel_ActList_status">
                <option value="2">11111</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="0">22222</option>
                <option value="1">33333</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But my code is not working to auto check in checkbox when I selected something in selectbox. Is there anything wrong in my jquery code? Pls give me some guideline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.sel_ActList_status').change(function() {
    $(this).parent('td').siblings().find(".chk_ActList_select").attr("checked", "true");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`This`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/9nr9B/), this is helpfull for you

```
$('.sel_ActList_status').change(function(){                                                     
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.sel_ActList_status').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, I'd suggest:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('checked',true);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r86sV/).

Though if you enable checking by selecting, or changing the select-box, you should probably enable un-checking by the same route (just to retain a consistent UI), so I'd amend the `select` elements, adding a 'none' `option` (`<option selected="selected" value="-1">None</option>`), and, if that's selected, un-check the box:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('checked', self.value !== '-1');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r86sV/1/).